# Did Frodo and Sam wear the same clothes during their journey to Mordor?

Tags: tolkiens-legendarium, the-lord-of-the-rings, clothing

I would like to know if Sam and Frodo wore the same clothes during their entire journey to Mordor.

Comment: My first thought was to say no, they each had their own set of clothes to wear, and did not have to share (for the most part - Frodo ends the journey wearing nothing but Sam's cloak). However, I'm sure Ibid has your actual intent.

Comment: The bigger question is, was anyone wearing the same clothes while *watching* all the movies?

Comment: No, but Gollum did - at least he appears to have been using the same loincloth since his first appearance in *The Hobbit*, and possibly since before he ever acquired the Ring - I'm guessing that's the remains of whatever clothes he had on back in his Smeagol days...

Answer (score 31, accepted):

### They did not

**The fellowship are given new clothes in Lothlorien**

> The Elves next unwrapped and gave to each of the Company the clothes they had brought. For each they had provided a hood and cloak, made according to his size, of the light but warm silken stuff that the Galadhrim wove. It was hard to say of what colour they were: grey with the hue of twilight under the trees they seemed to be; and yet if they were moved, or set in another light, they were green as shadowed leaves, or brown as fallow fields by night, dusk-silver as water under the stars. Each cloak was fastened about the neck with a brooch like a green leaf veined with silver.
> <sub>*The Lord of the Rings* Book II - Chapter 8 "Farewell to Lórien"</sub>

**At Cirith Ungol Frodo is captured and stripped. His clothes are all sent off to Barad Dur and he and Sam adopt orc clothing when they leave, which also helps them blend in.**

> He opened the bundle. Frodo looked in disgust at the contents, but there was nothing for it: he had to put the things on, or go naked. There were long hairy breeches of some unclean beast-fell, and a tunic of dirty leather. He drew them on. Over the tunic went a coat of stout ring-mail, short for a full-sized orc, too long for Frodo and heavy. About it he clasped a belt, at which there hung a short sheath holding a broad-bladed stabbing-sword. Sam had brought several orc-helmets. One of them fitted Frodo well enough, a black cap with iron rim, and iron hoops covered with leather upon which the evil Eye was painted in red above the beaklike nose-guard.
> 'The Morgul-stuff, Gorbag’s gear, was a better fit and better made,’ said Sam; 'but it wouldn’t do, I guess, to go carrying his tokens into Mordor, not after this business here. Well, there you are, Mr. Frodo. A perfect little orc, if I may make so bold-at least you would be, if we could cover your face with a mask, give you longer arms, and make you bow-legged. This will hide some of the tell-tales.’ He put a large black cloak round Frodo’s shoulders. `Now you’re ready! You can pick up a shield as we go.’
> <sub>*The Lord of the Rings* Book VI - Chapter 1 "The Tower of Cirith Ungol"</sub>

Comment: They also lost their original cloths in the Barrow Down incident.

Comment: I wouldn't be surprised if they had received more suitable travel clothes in Rivendell as well.

Comment: I don't have a quote handy, but Tolkein makes a point of noting that among traveling gear obtained by The Fellowship in Rivendell are fur-lined cloaks. Also, Frodo has Bilbo's Mithril shirt under all his outer clothing.

Comment: @Max - Arguably that would be before they set out to Mordor.

Comment: @dmedine - "All were well furnished by Elrond with thick warm clothes, and they had jackets and cloaks lined with fur." However, I can argue that since this is when they initially set out to Mordor it constitutes their *original* set of clothes, and so thus outside the scope of this answer.

Comment: @ibid Thank you for the quotation, but it is incorrect to suggest that my comment is not in the scope of the answer. The OP asked about clothing worn during the 'entire journey to Morder'. The stages between Rivendell and Rauros most definitely qualify as part of the journey to Mordor. At the Barrow Downs Sam and Frodo did not yet know that they were headed to Mordor, but I don't think one can argue that that episode was not part of the 'entire journey' either.

Comment: @dmedine - Well if they were wearing the Rivendell set the whole time then they would have been wearing the same clothes the whole journey. It's clothing they switch to *afterwards* that shows they switched outfits. (Though to be honest, if I had remembered it when I wrote the answer I'd have probably included it.)

Comment: @ibid I am saying that the journey to Mordor did not begin at Rivendell, but in the Shire.

Comment: @dmedine - When Frodo set out, his intent was to go to Rivendell. The journey from Rivendell constitutes a separate journey.

Comment: @ibid I don't think you can make that argument. When you place the stage from the Shire to Rivendell in the context of 'The road goes ever on and on...', Sam's comments about being part of tales, Bilbo's comments about the Bag End being on the same road that leads to the Lonely Mountain, etc. it is pretty clear that Tolkien's view is that every small journey is part of a larger one. I don't know of any textual evidence that supports your distinction. Frodo didn't know he was going to Mordor when he left the Shire, but he was quite literally on the road to Mordor from the beginning.

Comment: @ ibid ...and indeed Frodo was on a much larger journey. Ultimately Frodo is being lead to Valinor in the distant West --- a position of honor he earns by bearing The Ring. The books don't end at the Cracks of Doom, after all. In any case this argument is purely semantic. I think that all the OP really wanted to know is if the hobbits ever had a change of clothes on their travels.